# Jumping out of the burning building

Tags: homicide

Let's imagine there is a building on fire. And a girl is trapped on a 3rd floor. She jumps out of a window cause this is the only way to escape and lands on a fireman who just came to the site.

And.. Kills him by crushing into his body.

Can she be accused with involuntary manslaughter? Why/why not?

Answer (score 8):

The crime often called "involuntary manslaughter", or simply [manslaughter in the second degree](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=9A.32.070), is

> when, with **criminal negligence**, he or she causes the death of another
>   person

The standards for "criminal negligence" as well as "recklessness" are spelled out [here](https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=9A.08.010). The first term is defined as:

> A person is criminally negligent or acts with criminal negligence when
>   he or she fails to be aware of a substantial risk that a wrongful act
>   may occur and his or her *failure to be aware of such substantial risk
>   constitutes a gross deviation from the standard of care that a
>   reasonable person would exercise in the same situation*.

You can elaborate the above scenario with some details to make this be a criminally negligent act, but I assume the intent is to have this be a tragic accident. So for example, I assume that she did not see the fireman.
The law does not require you to die in a fire in case there is a remote possibility that you could injure another person in the course of saving yourself. Unless you add some evil intent on the girl's part ("I don't care if I land on that fireman, that's his job"), a reasonable person would act likewise and save their own life.